# Clustering Baseline Comparison, KMeans

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I'm working on an algorithm that makes a guess at K for kmeans clustering.  I guess I'm looking for a data set that I could use as a comparison, or maybe a few data sets where the number of clusters is "known" so I could see how my algorithm is doing at guessing K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first check the UCI repository for data sets:
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html?format=&task=clu&att=&area=&numAtt=&numIns=&type=&sort=nameUp&view=table

I believe there are some in there with the labels.

There are text clustering data sets that are frequently used in papers as baselines, such as 20newsgroups:
http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/

Another great method (one that my thesis chair always advocated) is to construct your own small example data set.  The best way to go about this is to start small, try something with only two or three variables that you can represent graphically, and then label the clusters yourself.

The added benefit of a small, homebrew data set is that you know the answers and it is great for debugging.

Comment: But homemade, synthetic datasets are not to be taken in consideration seriously about accuracy/convergence issues

Comment: True, rano, but if you are trying to find the optimal value for K, you really need to do that on a case-by-case basis anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are focused on `k`-means, have you considered using the various measures (Silhouette, Davies–Bouldin etc.) to find the optimal `k`?

In reality, the "optimal" k may not be a good choice. Most often, one does want to choose a much larger k, then analyze the resulting clusters / prototypes in more detail to build clusters out of multiple k-means partitions.

Comment: I'm working on a low cost means of determining k.  We have to be able to do for TBs of data so it has to be quick and parallelizable.  These methods look like they sacrifice performance in favor of accuracy.

Comment: You can still use them to validate whether your heuristic performs okay or not. Plus, k-means on TBs doesn't make a lot of sense, actually. Run it on a 1% sample (or less), and you will get essentially the same result. This is statistics. More data only changes the last few digits, unless you have bias. And if your code isn't good, you may even run into numerical issues with the full data set...

Answer (score 0):

The [iris flower dataset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set) is a good one to start with, that clustering works nicely on.

Download [here](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris)